# Understanding Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 5.10 ($ \varinjlim A_i =0 \rightarrow A_i =0$ for some $i$ ?)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Lemma 5.10 and stuck at understanding some delicate point :

[image]

Why the underlined statement is true? If $\varinjlim A_i =0 $ ($A_i$ are algebras), then $A_i=0$ for some $i$? An issue that makes me confused is following link :  [Zero direct limit of nonzero objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723039/zero-direct-limit-of-nonzero-objects) ; Existence of direct set of nonzero objects whose direct limit is zero. Is there a delicate difference between this link and our situation? What?

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference here between rings and modules, for (unital!) rings, being zero is characterised by the equation $1=0$. There's no analogue of that for modules, hence the different behaviour. (The examples in the linked post only address modules.)

We can use the explicit construction of a direct limit of algebras: we have $\varinjlim A_i = \bigsqcup A_i/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation saying that $a_i \in A_i$ is equivalent to $b_j \in A_j$ if there's some index $k$ such that $i \leq k$ and $j \leq k$ and $f_{ik}(a_i)=f_{jk}(b_j)$, where $f_{ik}:A_i \to A_k$ is the transition map of the direct system.

Now apply this definition of equivalence to the equation $[1]=[0]$, where $[-]$ denotes equivalence classes in the direct limit. Think of $1$ and $0$ as elements in some fixed $A_i$. Then by definition of the equivalence relation, we get some $k\geq i$ such that $f_{ik}(0)=f_{ik}(1)$. But $f_{ik}$ is a ring homomorphism, so this just means that $0=1$ in $A_k$, i.e. $A_k=0$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks! I somewhat understand :)~